# Model name and path after routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Here's my routing

```
resources :users do
  resources :tasks
  end
```

I have an error in the page new (form rendering)

That was before routing add and everything works great

```
= simple_form_for(@task) do |f|
```

Then I change it to

```
= simple_form_for(@user_task) do |f|
```

And got at error: undefined method `model_name'
How should I fix it?

Comment: Can you try `simple_form_for [@user, @task] do |f|`

Comment: @Nikhil undefined method `tasks_path'

Comment: does your task model has belongs to relation with users?

Comment: @Nikhil yes, it has

Comment: Can you post your `new` action from the controller?

Comment: def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

Comment: @Nikhil but in create
<i>@task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)<i>

Comment: can u specify `@user = current_user` and `@task = @user.tasks.new` and try in `new` action

Comment: Did the previous comment help?